# “Page Not Found” when navigating to site created with Gridsome & deployed on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, netlify, gridsome

I've created a new site using Gridsome deployed with Netlify, but I can't get the site to appear when accessed. Instead, Netlify says:

> Page Not Found
>
> Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
>
> < Back to our site

I tried updating my build settings based on the instructions of the creator of the [Gridsome starter template I'm using](https://gridsome.org/starters/forestry-starter), but the site still doesn't display. I've also updated the js-yaml version.

I've gone through the questions/answers for similar questions on here, but I haven't been able to figure this out. I'm new to web development, and I'm sure I'm missing one or more things contributing to the issue.

[My GitHub repo for this site](https://github.com/jeremybbauer/portfolio).

[The site](https://jeremybauer.space/).

I have the build log from Netlify. There are some errors in it. I don't want to put too much here, so here's a part from the end of the log.

```
12:18:36 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
12:18:36 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
12:18:36 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:18:36 PM: Finished processing build request in 55.729813394s
```

[A Gist for the whole build log](https://gist.github.com/jeremybbauer/fa999a14d097b481ec10ec04eb2eaf37).

Comment: You are getting runtime errors locally during development. Those same errors are happening during the build command, so the site is failing to build. Run your build command locally and you will see the errors. When you are running the develop command, you can see the runtime errors in the console of the browser inspector.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! Really appreciate it. I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure how to run my build command locally. I tried using my terminal in my local folder for the site and entering "build," but it said, "command not found."

Comment: depending on if you are using npm or yarn, your build command will be `npm run build` or `yarn build` respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help, [@talves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597114/talves)!

I was having trouble using the build commands because of being new to cli stuff and a permissions issue. I asked a friend about the build errors I was getting from Netlify, and he recommended I try removing and re-installing my node modules. Did that, still didn't work. I tried removing anything in the repo having to do with "journal" since `Failed to render /journal` kept appearing in the build log, but that didn't work either.

I googled `ReferenceError: _objectSpread is not defined after update` since that was in the build log after the journal error. I found [a comment on an issue noting the same error message](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10179#issuecomment-510080288) in the main Babel GitHub repo that suggested adding the following to the `package.json` file:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4"
  }
```

I added it, tried to build again, and it still failed but only gave me one error message it didn't show before—`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position`. I googled that message and got another issue on GitHub. [A comment on the issue](https://github.com/nexe/nexe/issues/333#issuecomment-307294347) noted a missing comma.

I went back to my `package.json` file and found that I didn't add a comma to the bracket above the new `"resolutions"` snippet. I added the comma, tried to build again, and it worked ✨ !

Sorry if this is long-winded! I thought it might be good to include my process on figuring this out in case others run into the same issues.